# Angular2 repeating selectors

Tags: javascript, angular

I am doing something like this, where I am declaring selectors on the fly.

```
<div ngFor="let x of y;let i = index;">
    <input *ngIf="i === 0" #selector0 type="number" value="{{item.value}}">
    <input *ngIf="i === 1" #selector1 type="number" value="{{item.value}}">
</div>
```

Is there a way to do it like below, where I don't need to repeat myself?

```
 <input #selector{{i}} type="number" value="{{item.value}}">

 <button (click)="submit(selector0)">
```

I'm not looking for an alternative way to do it, just wondering if dynamic selectors are possible.

Comment: how to do you use `#input{{i}}` in the class? maybe use `@ViewChildren` to get all inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we start here, where Angular defines these as a "Template Reference Variable":

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars

Okay, so let's try to find the source for that.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L34

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L430

So we're trying to parse out the element... lets see how it defines that:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L16

I'm going to put a breakpoint and see what's up.

EDIT:

I put a breakpoint in the "_parseAttr" function to see what it sees when it looks at the template reference:

Here is the call to find the binding:

```
var hasBinding = _this._parseAttr(isTemplateElement, attr, matchableAttrs, elementOrDirectiveProps, animationProps, events, elementOrDirectiveRefs, elementVars);
```

And what the debugger outputs for the attribute name:

```
attr = Attribute {name: "#testerno{{check}}", value: "", sourceSpan: ParseSourceSpan, valueSpan: undefined}
```

So it looks like the attribute name `name: "#testerno{{check}}"` is not parsed to see if {{check}} is an angular variable, it just interprets that as part of the string.

Therefore, you cannot do what you put above.  It thinks the reference name is `"#testerno{{check}}"` in this case.

Or, in your case, `selector{{i}}`.

Note that this makes sense because the "#" is used at the compiler level and is not present in your output html, so it would have no way of dynamically creating that reference.

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to a data attribute, then you can use javascript's querySelector.

```
<input attr.input="{{i}}" type="number" value="{{item.value}}">
```

Comment: ive updated my question to make it clearer - I want to do this all inline

Comment: I don't understand. Are you generating a button for each input as well? What is your real goal here?

Comment: I want to loop, and have my loop generate inputs, each of which will have a unique selector.